# NullPointerException when checking an array index for null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, stack

I'm attempting to make a stack and am running into issues where every time I attempt to check an index value I'm getting a NullPointerException.

```
private E[] items;

public Stack(Class<E> type) {
  E[] items = (E[]) new Object[10];
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
   if(items[0] == null){
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

When I run

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Stack<String> myStack = new Stack<>( String.class );
  System.out.println(myStack.isEmpty());
}
```

I'm getting a NullPointerException at

```
if(items[0] == null)
```

during the call to isEmpty().

Obviously I know items[0] should be null at this point and want to be able to do things based on if it is null or not, in this case returning true since the stack is empty.  How can I do this without getting a NullPointerException?

Comment: items itself is null.  YOu can't reference into a null array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line in the constructor

```
E[] items = (E[]) new Object[10];
```

creates a local variable but doesn't initialize your class field `items`. Use

```
items = (E[]) new Object[10];
```

The compiler will have raised a warning that `items` is not used so it is a good idea to pay attention to these warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Also, when making generic classes as such, I'd recommend doing it slightly differently. Instead of passing the class as a constructor parameter, you can declare the class as generic and it will work the same.

```
public class Stack<E>
{
    private E[] items;

    public Stack() {
        items = (E[]) new Object[10];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        if(items[0] == null){
           return true;
         }
         return false;
    }

    public E push(E item){
    ...
    }

    public E peek(){
    ...
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Then your main class would look like:

```
    Stack<String> myStack = new Stack<String>();
    myStack.push("hi");
    System.out.println(myStack.isEmpty());
```

This more closely emulates the conventions that java's built in generic classes have.